# Uploading Joomla website: DB prefix issue

Tags: database, joomla

I am trying to publish my website on hositng `260mb.org`. I uploaded all the files and updated the file `configuration.php`. But when I open the website I get the following message:

```
Table 'mb260_13057704_myDBtest.mb260_13057704_session' doesn't exist 
SQL=INSERT INTO `mb260_13057704_session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) 
VALUES ('df579d5b11e2220d4b137d3004cdfdf3', 0, '1367327108')
```

Well, the thing is that there is another prefix of my local db, and I don't know how to change it.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: The problem is that my local database is already created. Do I need to re-create all the tables? Is there any smart way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Akeeba Backup.

Install it on your localhost site - take a backup (.zip format is what I prefer), upload the .zip to your remote host, unzip the file and then navigate to your site.  It will walk you through a simple installer process (takes about 5 minutes for the first time) and your site and all appropriate database tables will be recreated and installed on the new remote host.

[Akeeba backup makes it SIMPLE](https://www.akeebabackup.com/) - and it will keep problems like this from happening (when you're manually moving things - which it sounds like you did).

You will need a fresh empty database on your host, then it will dump all the data in their during the installer process.